# Sum the columns in a list of dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to generate a single dataframe from the list of dataframes in which all columns  are same except one column 'Income'  which should be sum of the all the 'Income' in the list.

Here is my list of dataframe

```
mylist= structure(list(`1` = structure(list(ID = c(36L, 37L, 38L, 39L), Income = c(0, 0, 0, 9100)), .Names = c("ID", "Income"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), class = "data.frame"), `2` = structure(list(ID = c(36L, 37L, 38L, 39L), Income = c(0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("ID", "Income"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), class = "data.frame"), `3` = structure(list(ID = c(36L, 37L, 38L, 39L), Income = c(7360, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("ID", "Income"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), class = "data.frame")))

> mylist 
$`1`
  ID Income
1 36      0
2 37      0
3 38      0
4 39   9100

$`2`
  ID Income
1 36      0
2 37      0
3 38      0
4 39      0

$`3`
  ID Income
1 36   7360
2 37      0
3 38      0
4 39      0
```

This is what I want to do :

```
   ID   Income
34 36     7360
26 37        0
23 38        0
15 39     9100
```

I have tried to use reduce() to do the sum but it creates a separate column which I want to avoid :

```
Reduce(function(df1, df2) data.frame(df1[,], res=df1["Income"] + df2["Income"]),mylist)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the 'ID's in different `list` can be different, we `merge` the datasets using `Reduce`, and then do the `rowSums` of the output except the first one to create the 'Income' column.

```
r1 <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = "ID"), mylist) 
data.frame(r1[1], Income = rowSums(r1[-1]))
#   ID Income
#1 36   7360
#2 37      0
#3 38      0
#4 39   9100
```

---

If the 'IDs' are the same and in the same order for all the datasets in the `list`, we create the `data.frame` by extracting the 'ID' from the first element of 'mylist' and get the sum of the 'Income' using `Reduce` with `+`.

```
data.frame(mylist[[1]][1], Reduce(`+`, lapply(mylist, `[`, 'Income')))
```

Comment: Thanks for both the solutions. Just trying to figure out how it works .

Comment: @AndroidBeginner  In the first solution we are merging by 'ID' to create single dataset and then do the `rowSums` of the columns from 2:ncol(r1).  For the second solution, the `Reduce(`+`` is the doing the elementwise sum of each corresponding value in the `mylist`

Answer (score 0):

Why don you do rbind in your list of dataframes and then aggregate?

```
system.time(teste <- do.call("rbind",mylist))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.004   0.000   0.000 

system.time(r1 <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = "ID"), mylist))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.004   0.000   0.002 
aggregate(teste$Income, by=list(teste$ID), sum)
#  Group.1    x
#1      36 7360
#2      37    0
#3      38    0
#4      39 9100
```